# .htaccess Adding new rules to stop XSS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, xss

I have the following .htaccess files:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /generation/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /generation/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
Options -Indexes

# Turn off display_errors
php_flag display_errors off​
```

I then want to combine it with this example: to stop common XSS attacks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

How do i combine the rules from the second one into the new one. If i just add those query strings then my links inside the pages are just returning 404 pages...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are very likely to succeed in stopping XSS this way. If you look at the [OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) there are a lot ways to bypass simple XSS filters. Also I have to say I thought GLOBALS and _REQUEST were PHP concepts, not Apache, and as such wouldn't work there but I might be wrong.

The gist of what you are trying to do, is what Web Application Firewalls are doing. If you want to go down this route, I think you are better of using mod_security with the OWASP ruleset or something like that.

Still XSS is not an input problem, but an output problem. Sure you can stop many XSS flaws by filtering input, but in the end things that would normally be considered valid input, can also lead to XSS.

XSS has to be handled were user content is being rendered to the page, and encoded/escaped appropriately for the given context(s).